# Debugging Azure Functions throws error, "The pipeline was not run because a pipeline is already running. Pipelines cannot be run concurrently."

Tags: azure, powershell, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

#### Background

We followed [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-debug-powershell-local#debug-in-visual-studio-code) to debug a PowerShell Azure Function in VS Code. This is the error we experience.

> Internal Error - System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperationException: The pipeline was not run because a pipeline is already running. Pipelines cannot be run concurrently.

The GitHub issues indicate that this is an open issue that has not been resolved. Here is a starting place for the issues and comments about the problem: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/2776

### Question

Does that mean that debugging Azure PowerShell Functions with VS Code is currently broken? If not, what is the workaround to make the debugging work in VS Code?

### What Have We Tried?

1. Open the function in VS Code.
2. Add `Wait-Debugger` immediately after `params`.
3. Ensure the PowerShell session is using PowerShell Core 6+.
4. Stop the function in the Azure Portal.
5. Run `Get-PSHostProcessInfo` locally to ensure there is no `dotnet` process.
6. From VS Code, Attach to PowerShell Functions with the following config.

```
{
    "name": "Attach to PowerShell Functions",
    "type": "PowerShell",
    "request": "attach",
    "customPipeName": "AzureFunctionsPSWorker",
    "runspaceId": 1,
    "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
}
```

The error then appears.

Comment: Did you stop the function from running on Azure before trying to debug it locally? I remember getting an error one time I was local debugging and the function was active on Azure listening to the same queue

Comment: @tawman Yes. We have stopped the function on Azure before trying to start it locally.

Comment: A have the similar problem on all my 3 computer. I can't figure out why this happens. I have to close all PS window after debugging stopped, or else this error will come up. I tried Core tool 3 and 4, no changes.

Answer (score 1):

I  tried to reproduce the issue but i could not get any pipeline error in `Azure PowerShell function`  .

I have created a [`PowerShell function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-powershell) in vs code and deploy it to Azure after successfully test locally .

- installed extension in vs code **`PowerShell  .`**

[image]

After deploying stop the function app in Portal and trying to debug in my local as mentioned in the [`MS DOC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-debug-powershell-local#set-the-attach-point) When using PowerShell 7, we don't need to add the `Wait-Debugger` call in our code. After that we can refresh and debug .

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note: Please make sure to use PowerShell v5 or v7** .

Comment: I have 3 dev pc, and the problem reproduceable on all of them. You are lucky, something on your PC is different.